# How to smoothly move image automatically? in c#

Tags: c#, winforms, animation

I want to implement the code that image flows in an endless loop as background. To do this. 
I prepared 2 image object(picture box). then

I implement the move-image-code as below. ( I cleaned up some inessential code in this topic)

```
private void InitializeComponent()
{
    this.p1.Image = ((System.Drawing.Image)(resources.GetObject("picture")));
    this.p1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, -1000); // 0,0 // 0, -1000
    this.p1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(1000, 1000);

    this.p2.Image = ((System.Drawing.Image)(resources.GetObject("picture")));
    this.p2.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(0, 1000); // 0,0 // 0, -1000
    this.p2.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(1000, 1000);

    t1 = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(loop));
    t1.Start();
}

private void loop(Object o)
{
    CTMethod cttest = new CTMethod(movePictureBox);
    while (true)
    {
        try
        {
            this.Invoke(cttest);
            Thread.Sleep(10); // I updated..
        } catch(Exception e) {
            break;
       }
    }
}

private void movePictureBox()
{

    if (p1.Top == 0)
    {
        p2.Top = p1.Top-p2.Height;
    }

    if (p2.Top == 0)
    {
        p1.Top = p2.Top-p1.Height;
    }

    p1.Top++;
}
```

this code works well. But I've encountered some problems. 
the link line(connected line) of 2 images looks to be stuttering or be shaking occasionally.
I don't know why the images move like that. Does this have relations with lerp(interpolation)? 
If someone knows the reason, Could you help me please?

Comment: moving means animation. There's an [API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752312%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for that, because it's not as simple as setting coordinates and sleeping.

Comment: @DmitryLedentsov That API is for WPF, the question seems to be about Winforms (not that the OP's method is how it should be done).

Comment: @DmitryLedentsov That depends on what you're trying to achieve. some kinds of movement might be well suited for animation with the API, some not so much.

Comment: If instead of moving two images you stick two copies of the image together then you will not get a stuttering join.

Comment: @Rotem, Timothy Groote: indeed. The "Related" box contains a couple of valid examples

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might be because you're using `System.Drawing.Point`

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.point%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

This means the position determined by `System.Drawing.Point` will snap to whole numbers, causing one-pixel jumps during animations.

You might want to use `System.Drawing.Pointf` (since this uses floating point numbers rather than integers)

The same goes for `System.drawing.size`, which describes width and height in integers

[MSDN on system.drawing.size](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.size.width(v=vs.90).aspx)

Unfortunately, all Winforms controls (as Rotem pointed out) use `System.Drawing.Point`, making them inherently unsuitable for smooth animation.

You're probably better off drawing the pictures right to a `Graphics` object.

Comment: How does one use a `PointF` as the location of a `Control`, which is a `Point`, and not a `PointF`?

Comment: Err, i think the location of the control is a `Point`... Size is a `size`

Comment: Sorry, fixed my comment. The point still stands though. The issue being that in order to assign the value, it must be truncated to an integral `Point`.

Comment: You're right, so if you want smooth animation, a `PictureBox` (or any `Control`) isn't going to cut it.

Comment: Thank you for your all comments.So.. How can I overcome that problem?is there any other solution except for using graphic object?

Comment: Well, i tried running your example, but i can't see any of the jitter you're speaking of. Could it be your system can't keep up with the 2 millisecond sleep in your animation thread?
Try sleeping for a little bit longer.

Comment: Also, game engines tend to have a dynamically scaling render timeout so they can correct for that kind of "jitter". Unless you want to figure all that out, looking for a library where this problem has already been solved for you might be a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

You can try add this code in your form constructor,

```
SetStyle( ControlStyles.ResizeRedraw, true );
SetStyle( ControlStyles.UserPaint, true );
SetStyle( ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint, true );   
SetStyle( ControlStyles.OptimizedDoubleBuffer, true );
```

It's not good choice for custom drawing in WinForms, XNA is good choice, it paint with a double buffer.

Comment: Winforms can paint with a double buffer and can capably handle simple drawing.