# How would I make a moving, smooth image background in C# (Visual Studio 2019)

Tags: c#, visual-studio

The title speaks for itself, but how would I even start on this. I'm fairly new to C# so I won't know how to do this right away. Would I just constantly set the location of the image with cosine waves + sine waves?

I'm making an application in .NET Framework on Visual Studio 2019, and this is how I would like for the background to look

https://www.videvo.net/video/4k-motion-background-319/452375/
Would I be able to achieve this effect? How would the math look like? 
Tell me if you need more information.

Comment: Maybe not enough information to answer your question.  In what framework are you trying to animate an image?  [tag:winforms]?  [tag:unity3d]?  [tag:wpf]?  Something else?  And exactly what effect are you trying to achieve?  Moving a static image around inside some background window, or something else?  The more precise you can make your question, the greaterr the chance somebody will be able to volunteer to answer it.  See: [ask] and https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/ and also https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging

Comment: Oh, thanks. I'll edit it more.

Comment: There's lots of different graphics frameworks available in .net though, including the ones mentioned above.  In order to help you we need to know which you are using.  E.g. for [tag:winforms] see maybe [How to smoothly move image automatically? in c#](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27500959).  Also, Visual Studio is an [IDE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integrated_development_environment) not a framework.

Comment: Oh, thanks. Also that link 'How to smoothly move image automatically? in c#' helps a lot. Thank you

Comment: No, the title doesn't say enough: What are you targetting: Winforms, WPF, ASP..? 
YOU should __always__ TAG your questions correctly so one can see it on the questions page!